# Drush 6 on Windows not doing anything

Tags: installation, drush

I've installed Drush 6 on Windows using [this installation package](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/6.0.0/Drush-6.0-2013-08-28-Installer-v1.0.21.msi) and have ensured that the following is in my PATH variable:

> C:\ProgramData\Drush\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Drush\Php

When I open the Drush Command Prompt and type "drush status", nothing happens. The cursor moves a line down and blinks as if it's working on executing the command, but nothing is shown, and the process never ends. I have to Cntl+C to get out of it.

The same thing happens in Git Bash. No error messages, nothing. Just the ever blinking cursor. Any idea what's happening or how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It was a problem with the reverse-proxy we're using. I installed a different version of drush in cygwin and tried to run it. Here it paused like I described above, but after a minute showed me this error:

> Drush needs a copy of the PEAR Console_Table library in order to function, and the attempt to download this file automatically failed.
>   To continue you will need to download the 1.1.3 package from http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Table, extract it into C:\cygwin64\usr\local\src\drush/lib directory, such that Table.php exists at C:\cygwin64\usr\local\src\drush/lib/Console_Table-1.1.3/Table.php.

I installed this package manually and now things are working. I just didn't realize Drush was trying to download extra content.